# Converting substring to DATE with str_to_date

Tags: mysql, database

I've got probably what is a very simple issue. However, I've researched extensively and haven't found a solution yet. Basically, I want to convert a modified string variable into the DATE format (specifically `%Y`).

I have a column variable called `dob`, which includes dates in the `VARCHAR` format. The values of these strings vary and can look like any of the following: `01 JAN 1900`, `ABT 1960`, or `Unknown`. Nonetheless, the year is always the last four digits, so I'm grabbing the year by creating a substring. But I want to convert that substring into a `YEAR` format. My thought is that I need to use `str_to_date` to accomplish this.

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT dob, STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(dob, -4), "%Y") as YEAR
FROM person_table;
```

Upon running it, I only get `NULL` values. Is there something I'm missing?

Here are my MySQL specs:

```
innodb_version: 5.7.20
protocol_version: 10
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Providing SQL Mode Information:

```
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Variable_name | Value |
+ --------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Upon running the query `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2009','%Y');` I get `NULL` and the following warning:

```
I get the following warning:
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2009' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What is a 'year date format'? And what 'date' would it have?

Comment: I should've clarified. What I mean is that the substring needs to be converted to a `YEAR` format. I'll edit my post to make that clearly. My thought process is that I need to use the `str_to_date` function to accomplish that.

Comment: What part of the problem does `SUBSTRING(dob, -4)` not solve?

Comment: Show us `show variables like 'sql_mode'` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_to_date` returns a `date` type, and only a year is an incomplete date. `str_to_date` will fill in the incomplete parts with zeroes ***unless*** you have [`no_zero_dates`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) mode enabled. This is part of [Strict SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) which is the default in MySQL 8.0; it avoids the worst of MySQL's quirks.

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range

Without Strict SQL Mode, MySQL will turn "2009" into the invalid date 2009-00-00.

```
mysql> set sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2009','%Y');
+--------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2009','%Y') |
+--------------------------+
| 2009-00-00               |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With Strict SQL Mode it will not.

```
mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode';
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                 |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2009','%Y');
+--------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2009','%Y') |
+--------------------------+
| NULL                     |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                   |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2009' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

To solve your problem, instead of trying to do a one-size-fits-all conversion, I would recommend trying several formats from most to least specific using [`coalesce`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp). You will have to add the missing date parts as needed.

```
select coalesce(
  str_to_date(dob, '%d %b %Y'),
  str_to_date(concat(dob, '-01-01'), 'ABT %Y-%m-%d')
)
from person_table;
```

As this is very ugly to do, I also would recommend adding a proper `date` column and doing an `update` to convert from the messy string dates to proper `date`s. Then query the new column going forward.

```
alter table person_table add column dob_date date;

update person_table
set dob_date = coalesce(
  str_to_date(dob, '%d %b %Y'),
  str_to_date(concat(dob, '-01-01'), 'ABT %Y-%m-%d')
)
where dob_date is null;
```

You can then check for people with a null `dob_date`, examine their `dob` field, and adapt your conversion. Iterate as needed.

---

***UPDATE***

> To add, yes, I need the year 2020 as opposed to the string. The reason being is because I need to compare the year values.

As strings they will not compare as you need. Strings compare character by character. `'200'` is greater than the string `'1999'`.

```
mysql> select '1999' < '2000';
+-----------------+
| '1999' < '2000' |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select '1999' < '200';
+----------------+
| '1999' < '200' |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You need to cast them to signed integers.

```
mysql> select cast("1999" as signed) < cast('2000' as signed);
+-------------------------------------------------+
| cast("1999" as signed) < cast('2000' as signed) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               1 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast("1999" as signed) < cast('200' as signed);
+------------------------------------------------+
| cast("1999" as signed) < cast('200' as signed) |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              0 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So your query would be...

```
select dob, cast(substring(dob, -4) as signed) as year
from person_table;
```

Comment: While it may explain the NULLs, I don't think this addresses the OP's perceived problem.

Comment: @Strawberry How so?

Comment: In the context of your earlier comment, I'm puzzled by your question.

Comment: @Strawberry How does this not address the perceived problem? What do you see as the perceived problem?

Comment: The OP appears to perceive '2020' as being somehow different from 2020.

Comment: @Strawberry In MySQL there is a difference between the varchar '2020' and the [`year`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) 2020; I don't know if that matters to the OP. I interpreted the question as wanting to extract the date, but settling on just the year, so I covered date normalization; I like normalization. An answer about extracting just the year would be a good compliment.

Comment: To add, yes, I need the [`year`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) 2020 as opposed to the string. The reason being is because I need to compare the year values. My end goal is to identify the oldest and youngest individuals in this table. For that comparison, I thought I would need to convert the string value to a date value and then extract the year. If there is a way I can convert the string to a year format, then that would work as well.

Comment: @Strawberry Note there is also a difference between '2020' and 2020 when it comes to comparison.

Comment: Using `cast` worked for my needs! Thank you so much for your excellent explanation, @Schwern

Comment: I still don't see what problem this solves, that substring() doesn't. But hey, whatever floats your boat